# BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) => The parameter onChanged can't have a value of null

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I've copied/pasted some sample code for creating a custom BoxDecoration:

```
class FrameDecoration extends Decoration {
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) {
    return _CustomDecorationPainter();
  }
```

I get this error:

> The parameter 'onChanged' can't have a value of 'null' because of its
> type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
>
> Try adding either an explicit non-null default value or the 'required'
> modifier.

OK, that makes sense: it's a null safety issue.  My pubspec.yaml "environment": `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`

So I try adding "required":

```
class FrameDecoration extends Decoration {
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter(required [onChanged]) {
    return _CustomDecorationPainter();
  }
```

This time the error is:

> 'FrameDecoration.createBoxPainter' ('BoxPainter Function(void
> Function())'] isn't a valid override of 'Decoration.createBoxPainter'
> ('BoxPainter Function('void Function()])').

I tried several other things - no joy.

Both messages also say:

> The onChanged argument ... can be omitted if there is no change that
> the painter will change.

I tried "no parameters" ("createBoxPainter()"), and I tried an empty list ("createBoxPainter([])").  Still no joy.

All I want is to create my own "Decoration" class, with a custom "paint()" method.

Q: What's the correct syntax for omitting onChanged from createBoxPainter()?

Q: What's the recommended syntax for "createBoxPainter()" in this example?

---

pedro pimont gave me the syntax I was lookingfor:

```
 @override
 BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) {
   return _CustomDecorationPainter();
 }
 // <= Explicitly adding the type, and making it nullable, resolved the compile error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `createBoxPainter` from the `Decoration` class you're trying to override takes an optional `VoidCallback onChanged` parameter so if you don't provide it with a default value, you must also mark it as **nullable** using `?`, try this:

```
BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged])
```

Also, although none of these below will work, regarding the Dart syntax, you're marking an optional parameter as required, this is not allowed.

Either use a named parameter to use the required keyword using `{}`:

```
BoxPainter createBoxPainter({required Function onChanged})
```

Or make it required by removing `[]`

```
BoxPainter createBoxPainter(Function onChanged)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ... but NONE of these suggestions worked: `BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback onChanged])` => "can't have a value of null"; `BoxPainter createBoxPainter({required Function onChanged})` or `BoxPainter createBoxPainter(Function onChanged)` => "isn't a valid override"

Comment: fixed it, can you try it again now?

Comment: if you don't provide an default value to a optional parameter you have to mark it as nullable, I had forgot about it

Comment: Your second and third suggestions both still fail (COMPILE ERROR: "isn't a valid override").  But your corrected version of `BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged])` works like a charm.  Thank you!